# update.php error, not showing index

Tags: php, xml, logging, warnings, updates

not opened my homepage..not showing index...(but i'm showing admin page)
i'm so little bit speak English ...
help me please .. T.T

```html
2016-01-13T05:11:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-13T05:11:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-13T05:11:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
```

this log..what problem ?...

```html
2016-01-13T02:53:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090198_Layout2/layout/bestseller.xml
2016-01-13T02:53:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090198_Layout2/layout/featured.xml
2016-01-13T02:53:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090198_Layout2/layout/tempmela.xml
2016-01-13T02:53:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090198_Layout2/layout/manufacturer.xml
2016-01-13T02:53:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090198_Layout2/layout/newproducts.xml
2016-01-13T02:53:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090198_Layout2/layout/specialproducts.xml
2016-01-13T02:53:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/moneybookers.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/core.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/directory.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/cms.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog_msrp.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalogsearch.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/payment.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090198_Layout2/layout/sales.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/billing_agreement.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/recurring_profile.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/cataloginventory.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/shipping.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml
2016-01-13T02:58:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/paypal.xml
```

```html
2016-01-13T01:24:11+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
2016-01-13T01:24:11+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
2016-01-13T01:24:11+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
```

please help me !!!

Comment: please show your php code or use this htmlspecialchars_decode();

Comment: one more solution: $xml = preg_replace('#&(?=[a-z_0-9]+=)#', '&amp;', $xml);
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);

Comment: Do you know where is my php file ? ?